# Convert c time function delphi

Tags: c, delphi, typeconverter

C code looks like this;

```
clock_t clock_start, clock_end;

      clock_start = clock();

      if ((pass = create_pass(100, time(NULL))) == NULL)
         crate_pass_err("passerror");
```

What exactly is time here?

I do with delphi;

```
function create_pass(sz:DWORD;Sd:DWORD):Pointer;stdcall;external DLL;

start:=gettickcount;
DecodeTime(now, hours, mins, secs, milliSecs);
timeread:= strtoint(FormatDateTime('NNSSZZZ',time));

    pass:=create_pass(100,timeread); // timeread or millisecs or start ?
```

Which of these will give the same result? Or is there another solution?

edit: The results I get in the program output are not exactly the same. What exactly is "time" doing in c code? I am trying to find it. ( 
output of c code : "stacksample" , output of delphi code "%Oê^%O" 
I'm trying to convert my password program to Delphi )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`time()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time) is a C function that *usually* returns the number of seconds that have elapsed since the Unix epoch, January 1 1970 00:00 UTC (I say *usually* because the value actually returned by `time()` is not mandated by the C standard, but *most* implementations are done this way).

A Delphi translation of the C code you have shown would look something like this:

```pascal
uses
  ..., DateUtils;

var
  clock_start, clock_end: DWORD;
begin
  ...
  clock_start := GetTickCount;
  pass := create_pass(100, DWORD(DateTimeToUnix(Now, False)));
  if (pass = nil) then
    crate_pass_err('passerror');
  ...
  clock_end := GetTickCount;
  ...
end;
```